# PhpStorm built-in server: Debug incoming requests

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

I am (locally) hosting a PHP script with PhpStorms built-in Server. Is there a way to debug an incoming HTTP request?

I know that there is the "PHP HTTP Request" run-configuration, which allows you to perform a request and debug it, but somehow my problem only occurs when the requests is coming from an other application. I have no clue why.

Currently, I use the "PHP Built-in Web Server" run-configuration to host the script.

Thanks!

Comment: So .. what is your problem exactly? P.S. (just to make things clear; possibly you already know this) Please note that "PhpStorm's built-in web server" and "PHP Built-in Web Server" run-configuration are 2 different things.

Comment: My problem is, that I do not know if there is a way to debug the PHP code that gets executed, when an external client sends a HTTP request.

Comment: And what is the difference between these two? I thought that the run-configuration "PHP Built-in Web Server" uses "PhpStorm's built-in web server".. Is that wrong?

Comment: 1) "PHP Built-in Web Server" -- is served by actual [PHP itself directly](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) while "PhpStorm's built-in web server" uses [PhpStorm's own simple built-in web server](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+Built-in+Webserver+in+PhpStorm) (where .php files are served by your default PHP Interpreter). First one will have typically URLs like `localhost:8000/index.php` while second will be `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/index.php`

Comment: 2) *"that I do not know if there is a way to debug the PHP code that gets executed, when an external client sends a HTTP request"* You can add xdebug parameter to the requested URL (if possible; either COOKIE or GET/POST parameter -- https://xdebug.org/docs/remote -- the "HTTP Debug Sessions" section). Otherwise -- just use `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your php.ini -- xdebug will attempt to debug **every single request** (which can have undesired effects in some cases).

Comment: Ideally you want to use "zero-config" approach (the green phone handle icon). I suggest checking these manuals: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: Thanks, that sounds great. I will try it out and add the answer if everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, following was the solution: Adding `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1` to the request parameters and listening to debugger connections in PhpStorm (I use xdebug).

Big thanks to @LazyOne for giving me the answer! [His suggestion](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm) really helped.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this post while following all the details but it's still not working.
[Check my answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67987596/4641980)